# Jupyter Notebook (Python) - Different outputs based on 'Run All' button vs manually running cells?

Tags: python, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

Hi Stack Overflow community,

I'm relatively new to Python and I've been working on a project for an online course using dataframes, etc but I encountered the following Jupyter issue:

Running all the cells in Jupyter provide a different/incorrect output than running them manually.

I get a Key Error that my column 'genre' doesn't exist in my dataframe when I use "Run All":

[Run All button - outputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2N9K7.png)

However, when I run those last five cells manually it works as intended:

[Running cells manually - outputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Htv8Z.png)

When running all the cells, the code cell #36 doesn't register the 'genre' but it does when I ran them manually (as shown in cell #37's output). I tried restarting my kernel but the issue remains.

The cell #36 has the following code:

`df_gprofit = df_genre.groupby(df_genre['genre'], as_index = False)['genre_profit'].sum().sort_values(by = ['genre_profit'], ascending = False).reset_index(drop =True)`

I'm creating a sub-dataframe with it but unsure why Run All is giving a different output. Please let me know and thanks!!

EDIT: I would like to know if anybody has encountered this issue before/ possible solutions as I thought Run All was straightforward in its output method.

Comment: Your two images don't reflect what you say they represent in your title or description. The cell numbering doesn't match. When you do 'Run All', the cell kicking out an error is cell number 40. What looks like the same cell has a number of 45 in 'Running cells manually - outputs'. If you restarted the kernel & did 'Run All' or restarted the kernel & stepped through running each manually, you should end up with the same numbering. We have no idea what code you ran in the other few cells we don't see. Please provide code in support of screenshots and a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Hi Wayne, you're right, I should of clarified. I manually ran the cells from output order 36# so that's why they are showing with the different order the second time around. However, I just ran all cells manually and the issue remains. So the issue is not with the Running All as I previously thought! I think I figured it out, I'll update my question in a bit

Answer (score 0):

Wayne, thank you for your comment! This time around, I ran all the cells manually and it does in fact provide the same output as the Run All option so in that sense my question of Jupyter Run All option vs manually is answered.

The issue is with my code (#36). I've been able to fix it by adding the same code twice. I'm not sure why I would need to have the code run twice but I'll check that further and create a new question altogether focused on this if necessary instead :).

Comment: Yes, that makes a bit more sense from the point of Jupyter. You were making a hidden state in the notebook and so your so-called manual run worked because of that. The "hidden state" that can arise like that is one reason some folks disfavor notebooks. Anyway, I you have better luck if you separate out that convoluted cell #36. I generally make a groupby object and process that. Take that apart and you may find the step that was the problem or even find it works if done step-wise.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).